# JavaFX TextArea does not append text properly

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to build a simple calculator using TDD, so I have a TextArea that is right aligned to display the results and 20 buttons. Everytime one of the digit buttons are pressed it just appends the digit to the TextArea, the same thing was supposed to happen when I press the dot button. But instead it places the dot as the first character in the TextArea, only when I press a new digit the dot goes to its proper place.

So for example, if I press 9 and then 8 the TextArea shows "98", now if the dot is pressed the result will be ".98", finally if 7 is pressed the result is "98.7".

The expected result when I pressed the dot button should have been "98.".

I created a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example bellow

FXMLDocument.fxml:

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="175.0" prefWidth="256.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" fx:controller="mcv.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="buttonNine" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="100.0" onAction="#handleButtonNine" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="69.0" text="9">
         <font>
            <Font size="24.0" />
         </font></Button>
      <TextArea fx:id="textArea" editable="false" focusTraversable="false" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="14.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="66.0" prefWidth="221.0" wrapText="true">
         <font>
            <Font size="35.0" />
         </font>
      </TextArea>
      <Button fx:id="buttonDot" layoutX="169.0" layoutY="100.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonDot" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="69.0" text=".">
         <font>
            <Font size="24.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

FXMLDocumentController.java:

```
@FXML
private TextArea textArea;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
}

private void appenToResult(String ch){
    textArea.appendText(ch);
}

@FXML
void handleButtonDot(ActionEvent event) {
    appenToResult(".");
}

@FXML
void handleButtonNine(ActionEvent event) {
    appenToResult("9");
}
```

As you can see the code is very simple. It should be working, my only clue is that this is a bug with the TextArea when the Node Orientation is set to RIGHT_TO_LEFT. If node orientation is set to INHERIT or LEFT_TO_RIGHT it works as expected. Thank you.

Comment: Why ***do*** you change the node orientation? You're not using arabic or some other language. This results in the weird treatement of the `.` character. If it's appended, it's considered the end of sentence and since you add digits later, this assumption is emended. Why are you using such a small `TextArea` anyway instead of using a `TextField`?

Comment: I do that because I want to have the text right aligned, just like you have the option in any text writing software (left, center, right os justfied). It is usual in calculators to have the text right aligned, now I don’t know if changing the node orientation was the right way to go about this, but it is what I found on my research. Do you know how to do it any other way? Thank you.

Comment: `TextField` would allow you to set the alignment. You don't seem to be using line breaks and even if you did you would probably only see a single line in the viewport.

Comment: I see, ok I will change it to TextField to see if it works.

Comment: @fabian It worked, could you please post it as an answer? Thank you.